# Как выполнить alert() в последнюю очередь?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такая функция, при её выполнении сначала выводится модальное окно, и только потом воспроизводиться аудио.
Нужно, чтоб сначала воспроизводилось аудио, а потом выводилось модальное окно.
Как это осуществить? И почему порядок выполнения не сходится с последовательностью в коде?

```js
function result(){
 if(total>0){
 $('#audio').get(0).play();
 alert('Новых заказов:'+total);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно, `play()` не является атомарной функцией: внутри происходит асинхронная предзагрузка необходимого для старта файла фрагмента, а затем уже происходит запуск. Вызывая `alert()` вы останавливаете поток выполнения, тем самым не давая запуститься аудио.

Выход: отслеживать [события `audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events), например, `playing`, и уже в обработчике события показывать `alert()`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#audio').on('playing', function() {
    alert('test');
  });
  $('#audio').get(0).play();
});
```

```html
<audio id="audio">
  <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Принцип вашего решения понял, оно натолкнуло меня на верное решение. С собитием `playing` не работает, а вот с событием `ended` получилось! Не могли бы вы дать краткое толкование понятию "атомарная функция" ? (лишь примерно догадываюсь, что это)

Comment: А вы определяете обработчик события `playing` как у меня в примере — перед вызовом `play()` или как у вас в примере, после? Если после, то не работает скорее всего по этой причине. Не атомарная — имеется в виду, что состоит из нескольких подфункций, поэтому так себя ведёт.

Comment: @ArtemKorsunov ставлю плюс .я не знал про атомарных функций

Answer (score 1):

Отслеживать события `audio`. Показать alert() в обработчике события `ended`.

```js
$(function() {
$('#audio').get(0).play();
  $('#audio').on('ended', function() {
    alert('test');
  });
});
```